# Как на Python определить фон ячейки в Excel?

Tags: python, xlrd, excel

Использую расширения xlrd для работы с файлами Excel. Не могу разобраться, каким образом определить цвет фона ячейки, на которую в настоящий момент указывает курсор. Кто сталкивался с подобной задачей?

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, что при определении цвета необходимо пройти следующим путём:

```
Cell.xf_index
Book.xf_list
XF.background
XFBackground.background_colour_index
Book.colour_map
```

Если по-русски, то у ячейки есть индекс стиля, у книги есть список стилей, в котором по индексу можно найти стиль.. у стиля есть описание бэкграунда.. а у него, в свою очередь, есть индекс цвета. У книги есть палитра цветов и в ней, по индексу из стиля фона, можно найти сам цвет. + есть ещё цвета, не входящие в палитру, а являющиеся константами.

UPD: вот тут написано про индексы и константные цвета (см. раздел **The Palette; Colour Indexes**)

https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал последовать совету: получается весьма забавная картина. Код работает, но получаемый из ячейки индекс словаря с палитрой цветов соответствует значению None:

```
xls = xlrd.open_workbook('excel_file.xls',formatting_info=True)
sup2 = xls.sheet_by_index(0)
s = Styles(xls)
cellStyle=s[sup2.cell(2,1)]
print 'CELL: ', sup2.cell(2,1).value
cellXF = cellStyle.xf
print xls.colour_map[cellXF.background.background_colour_index]
```

Проверял позиционирование - обращаюсь првильно, ошибки в индексе ячейки нет ( Причина сего не совсем понятна....

Comment: Это либо баг в xlrd, либо там обращение к словарю так сделано, что при обращении к несуществующему не случается ошибка. А вы не смотрели в таблицу константных индексов?